# When does my browser fetch images / make get requests? [when using Jquery]

Tags: jquery, image, fetch

I recently worked on the development of a marketing site - which relies on JQuery. Used the bxslider jquery plugin for carousels on the homepage.

My problem is - when visiting the homepage using Chrome browser, there is a momentary and perceptible delay before all of Jquery code including the slider plugin is executed and then the images are fetched from the web server and then rendered.

1. How do I know exact point in the javascript code when the browser starts fetching images (seemingly all at once). Any debug/F12 options? I believe it happens on Document ready, but cant seem to trace that code.
2. How can I tell jquery, to force certain parts of my homepage to start downloading the images and rendering them?

Regards,
Arun

Comment: [Preloading images with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: For starters the timing is different for images already in the initial html vs images inserted by script. More details needed. Also what specific problem are you trying to solve?